# Shortest way to generate randomly "-1" or "+1" in C#

Tags: c#, random

What is the shortest way to generate "-1" or "+1" in C#? I need it to give a random direction to a vector.

Comment: What have you tried to do yourself?  What problems have you had with your implementation?

Comment: The shortest I can come up with is `1`. Any further requirements? ;)

Comment: @MagnusHoff Have you got that number by a fair dice roll?! :D

Comment: Obligatory Reference: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Looks more like a code golf than a serious programming problem...

Comment: return (moon.Alignment == MoonAlignment.WithSaturn) ? -1 : 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an *even* distributions of -1 and 1, you can use:

```
Random rand = new Random();

while({condition})
{
    int next = rand.Next(2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Why dont make a simple math operation ? I think about this :`rand.Next(2) - 1`

Comment: @aloisdg that would give you -1 or 0, not -1 or 1.

Comment: Yes you are right. What about this : `rand.Next(2) * 2 - 1`

Comment: @aloisdg that would work.

Comment: @D Stanley I don't know what is better. I will benchmark this. I am curious.

Comment: @aloisdg: Why is the faster one necessarily the better one? Is this likely to be the slowest thing in the program? Optimize for ease of reading before you optimize for speed.

Comment: @EricLippert I am agree with you. I like to find another way to do something. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

There's :

```
var r=new Random();
int direction = (r.Next(2) == 1 ? 1 : -1);
```

`r.Next(2)` will produce either a `0` or a `1` on each call.

or:

```
int directions[] = {1, -1};
int direction = directions[r.Next(2)];
```